# Config Git repository to hold just top n'th commit

Tags: git

I want to init a git repository to hold just the top 10 commits.

for example, if I commit and push the 11'th one automatically it will remove the 1st commit and the 2nd commit now be the 1st one.

I want this to take effect in the local and also in the remote repository and delete an old commit in real.

is it possible?

Comment: Git won't do that by itself. Sounds like you want a backup software instead.

Comment: Yes, a backup platform based on git.

Comment: There is no such a config option, however it's scriptable. This is easy to implement by using git plumbing commands. Interactive git rebase, if it can be automated and if tree/text conflicts resolution can be automated too, seems to be able to do the trick too.

Comment: Wow, that's a really weird use of Git. Git is all about preserving all history, and not letting it expire. A scripted solution would basically have to recreate a brand new repo with no commits in common every time it removed the oldest commit.

Comment: @joanis Why weird? Git is literally _a stupid content tracker_ (according to its documentation) and really allows rewriting history purging commits from the history (as well as the space they take). I think the OP merely wants to have both content history and transport (push/pull) support that would work well with a Git-friendly environment (a scenario, say, publishing a foo-bar dataset to GitHub :D). I would say, that the OP's scenario is pretty close to a single-commit repository whose only commit is constantly  amended (but 10 commits queue for the OP's scenario.)

Comment: @terrorrussia-keeps-killing Well, yeah, when you look at it that way, I guess that makes sense. Git does offer some useful functionality here, so why not!

Comment: Is this a theoretical question or you are trying to solve some actual problem by this? While it possibly can by done with some scripts managing a repo with more than a single master branch will be a nightmare.

Answer (score 1):

Git is not really suitable here, and the reason is simple enough: you cannot *remove* a commit.

What you *can* do is notice that you have ten commits in a row:

```
A <-B <-C <-D <-E <-F <-G <-H <-I <-J
```

where commit `A` is your root (initial) commit, commit `B` refers back to commit `A`, commit `C` refers back to commit `B`, and so on up through commit `J` which refers back to commit `I`.  But *all commits are completely read-only* so commit `B` *always* refers back to commit `A`, *forever*.

Hence, to "get rid of" commit `A`, what you must do is make a *new root commit* that is like `B` except that it does not point to `A`:

```
A <-B <-C <-D <-E <-F <-G <-H <-I <-J

B'
```

Having made `B'`, you can now make a new commit `C'` that is like `C` but points back to `B'` rather than to `B`.  Commit `C` cannot be used here because it *always* points to `B`, *forever*, and `B` always points to `A` forever.  But new copy `C'` points to `B'`:

```
A <-B <-C <-D <-E <-F <-G <-H <-I <-J

B'<-C'
```

Repeat for all 9 commits and you have:

```
A <-B <-C <-D <-E <-F <-G <-H <-I <-J

B'<-C'<-D'<-E'<-F'<-G'<-H'<-I'
```

You can now add a new commit `J'` that points back to `I'`, and you now have a new series of ten snapshots, which there is no 11th `A` snapshot.

The problem here is that you now have 20 snapshots.  You have 9 *reused* snapshots—the snapshot in `B'` matches that in `B`—and one new snapshot, for a total of 11 *unique* snapshots, but you have 20 snapshots, because none of the existing ten commits is *gone*.  Should you now move the one and only branch name to point to commit `J'`, you won't be able to *find* the old commits, and `git gc` will eventually remove them from *your* repository, but if you have sent this Git repository anywhere else in the past, that *other* copy of the repository still has the original ten commits too.

Since *every* repository retains *every commit it has ever had* as long as possible, all you're really doing is making things hard for yourself while still saving everything for ever, or at least a potentially very long time.  If you control all the Git repositories (all the copies), you can *force* them all to expire any reflogs and run `git gc` to discard each original chain of commits, but really, proper backup software would be a much better choice.

Still, if you really want to do this, you now know how.